# Create property at runtime

Tags: c#

is it possible to create a property on a type at runtime? My type "Account" has a predefined bunch of properties such has "ID" and "Account Name" and it implements INotifyPropertyChanged, I wanted to add properties to this type at runtime, so a getter and a setter and the setter would call a method Notify passing in it's property name i.e

```
public string Name
{
     get { return _name; }
     set
     {
          _name = value;
          NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
     }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Are you trying to re-invent `DataTable`?

Comment: Basically I am being sent data from a datastore and I get a fixed packet of columns and a varying packet. No idea how I can handle a varying packet.

Comment: What version of .Net you are using?

Comment: What is a purpose of creating properties at runtime? You will need to use them using reflection (again), because at compile-time they won't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but not with "normal" `CLR` types. You can achieve that, actually that type was created especially for functionalities like that: [DynamicObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.aspx)

Look on example code provided of the class that *implements* `DynamicObject`, like

```
public class DynamicDictionary : DynamicObject
{
   ...
}
```

and after you are able to use it like:

```
dynamic person = new DynamicDictionary();

// Adding new dynamic properties.      
person.FirstName = "Ellen";
person.LastName = "Adams";
```

Comment: Could he cheat it and use `public string this[string propertyName] { get{ } set { } }` where get and set would pull the property from a Dictionary?

Comment: Yes he can, but implementing this class he gets more potential from `DLR` (naturally if he needs it).

Comment: @Bob, see my answer on this thread : [How to create in C# WPF a DataGrid dynamic columns binded to an observable collection of dynamic properties types at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61456901/how-to-create-in-c-sharp-wpf-a-datagrid-dynamic-columns-binded-to-an-observable/61457444#61457444)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Reflection.Emit` to dynamically create new classes that inherit from your class, and then add the properties to that new type.
As it inherits your own type, it can be considered as being an "extension" for that type.

I must warn you that this path is a complicated one, and you will probably produce code that you will never understand again after finishing the job!

Also **you will have understand how MSIL code works**. It is a bit odd, and inverted thing. You have to do things quite the oposite way you would expect in a language such as C#. You must push and pop values from stacks to pass as argument to a function, and you must activelly discard unused return values from functions... and so on.

And **YES, I am trying to make you afraid of this**... it is such a painful way ;)

Consider other alternatives before falling to this one.

There is a lot of material in SO already on this matter: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reflection.emit

CodeProject article explaining Reflection.Emit:
[Dynamic Type Using Reflection.Emit](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/121568/Dynamic-Type-Using-Reflection-Emit)

Comment: I think that you gave the right clues, see also my answer on this thread : [How to create in C# WPF a DataGrid dynamic columns binded to an observable collection of dynamic properties types at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61456901/how-to-create-in-c-sharp-wpf-a-datagrid-dynamic-columns-binded-to-an-observable/61457444#61457444)

Answer (score 0):

Either you use a Dynamic Object or extend behavior via Extension Methods. I don't know of other options.

Answer (score -1):

no, that is not possible with c# objects

you can make dictionary like classes, which can store different properties like in the question with the DynamicObject

what you can do is is creating new class types by reflection, and they can contain new properties. but there is no easy way to access these

Comment: please add comments if you are downvoting, the answer IS correct.