# How to create in C# WPF a DataGrid dynamic columns binded to an observable collection of dynamic properties types at runtime

Tags: c#, dynamic, properties, binding, datagrid

I'm trying to create in C# WPF a DataGrid with dynamic columns binded to an observable collection of dynamic properties types created at runtime.

This is my code :

**View WPF**

```
<DataGrid
    ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollectionVM, Mode=OneWay}"
    AutoGenerateColumns="True">
</DataGrid>
```

Then in my **ViewModel** :

```
public class MyStatiClass
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}

// Main View Model, using MVVMLight library
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<MyStatiClass> _myCollectionVM = new ObservableCollection<MyStatiClass>();
    public ObservableCollection<MyStatiClass> MyCollectionVM
    {
        get => _myCollectionVM;
        set => Set(nameof(MyCollectionVM), ref _myCollectionVM, value);
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        MyCollectionVM.Add(new MyStatiClass() { ID = 1, Name = "Name1", Address = "15 Hollywood Street"});
    }
}
```

`MyStatiClass` contains as an example three properties but I want to generate as many properties as wanted dynamically at runtime. These properties will be generated elsewhere to fit some business needs.

I tried several methods like using `List<dynamic>`, `Dictionary<>` , `ExpandoObject`, ... , but each time, the `DataGrid` which uses reflection is displaying the first level properties passed in the type `MyStatiClass` and not the real properties of `MyStatiClass` that I wanted.

My question is, How can I do this ?

Thank you for your help.
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same issue by the past and found this solution based on the **Excellent** article from [**Kailash Chandra Behera**](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/87b416/dynamically-create-a-class-at-runtime/).

The secret relies on using `System.Reflection.Emit` which provides classes that allow a compiler or tool to emit metadata and Microsoft intermediate language (MSIL) and optionally generate a PE file on disk. The primary clients of these classes are script engines and compilers.

For the curious and passionate, you can go ahead : [System.Reflection.Emit Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit?view=netcore-3.1) and [Introduction to Creating Dynamic Types with Reflection.Emit](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13337/Introduction-to-Creating-Dynamic-Types-with-Reflec)

**Solution** :

`List<dynamic>`, `Dictionary<>` , `ExpandoObject` cannot works because, reflection will be stalled on the first level hierarchy of your instance class `MyStatiClass`.
The only solution I found is to create dynamically the complete `MyStatiClass` at runtime including as instance namespace, class name, properties names, attributes, etc. .

**This is the ViewModel code fitting your question :**

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableCollectionEx<dynamic> _myCollectionVM = new ObservableCollectionEx<dynamic>();
    public ObservableCollectionEx<dynamic> MyCollectionVM
    {
        get => _myCollectionVM;
        set => Set(nameof(MyCollectionVM), ref _myCollectionVM, value);
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        MyClassBuilder myClassBuilder = new MyClassBuilder("DynamicClass");
        var myDynamicClass = myClassBuilder.CreateObject(new string[3] { "ID", "Name", "Address" }, new Type[3] { typeof(int), typeof(string), typeof(string) });

        MyCollectionVM.Add(myDynamicClass);

        // You can either change properties value like the following
        myDynamicClass.ID = 1;
        myDynamicClass.Name = "John";
        myDynamicClass.Address = "Hollywood boulevard";
    }
}
```

**Remark** : Compilation checks and Intellisense won't work will dynamic types, so take care of your properties syntax, otherwise you'd get an exception raised at runtime.

**Then the Dynamic Class Factory Builder which will build the full class at runtime :**

```
/// <summary>
/// Dynamic Class Factory Builder
/// </summary>
public class MyClassBuilder
{
    AssemblyName asemblyName;

    public MyClassBuilder(string ClassName)
    {
        asemblyName = new AssemblyName(ClassName);
    }

    public dynamic CreateObject(string[] PropertyNames, Type[] Types)
    {
        if (PropertyNames.Length != Types.Length)
        {
            throw new Exception("The number of property names should match their corresopnding types number");
        }

        TypeBuilder DynamicClass = CreateClass();
        CreateConstructor(DynamicClass);
        for (int ind = 0; ind < PropertyNames.Count(); ind++)
            CreateProperty(DynamicClass, PropertyNames[ind], Types[ind]);
        Type type = DynamicClass.CreateType();

        return Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    }

    private TypeBuilder CreateClass()
    {
        AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(asemblyName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
        ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("MainModule");
        TypeBuilder typeBuilder = moduleBuilder.DefineType(asemblyName.FullName
                            , TypeAttributes.Public |
                            TypeAttributes.Class |
                            TypeAttributes.AutoClass |
                            TypeAttributes.AnsiClass |
                            TypeAttributes.BeforeFieldInit |
                            TypeAttributes.AutoLayout
                            , null);
        return typeBuilder;
    }

    private void CreateConstructor(TypeBuilder typeBuilder)
    {
        typeBuilder.DefineDefaultConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.RTSpecialName);
    }

    private void CreateProperty(TypeBuilder typeBuilder, string propertyName, Type propertyType)
    {
        FieldBuilder fieldBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineField("_" + propertyName, propertyType, FieldAttributes.Private);

        PropertyBuilder propertyBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineProperty(propertyName, PropertyAttributes.HasDefault, propertyType, null);
        MethodBuilder getPropMthdBldr = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("get_" + propertyName, MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.HideBySig, propertyType, Type.EmptyTypes);
        ILGenerator getIl = getPropMthdBldr.GetILGenerator();

        getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, fieldBuilder);
        getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        MethodBuilder setPropMthdBldr = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("set_" + propertyName,
              MethodAttributes.Public |
              MethodAttributes.SpecialName |
              MethodAttributes.HideBySig,
              null, new[] { propertyType });

        ILGenerator setIl = setPropMthdBldr.GetILGenerator();
        Label modifyProperty = setIl.DefineLabel();
        Label exitSet = setIl.DefineLabel();

        setIl.MarkLabel(modifyProperty);
        setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, fieldBuilder);

        setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Nop);
        setIl.MarkLabel(exitSet);
        setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        propertyBuilder.SetGetMethod(getPropMthdBldr);
        propertyBuilder.SetSetMethod(setPropMthdBldr);
    }
}
```

Enjoy it.