# C# Dynamically add properties to a class for databinding in a datagrid

Tags: c#, data-binding

I have a list of business objects used as the datasource for a datagrid and I need to dynamically add properties to these business objects at runtime.  These dynamic properties will in turn dynamically add new columns to the datagrid.  The data is coming from a dynamic pivot operation in the database so there is no way to know in advance what the data grid will be receiving.

As  test I ran the code below which succeeded in databinding but did not give the intended results.

```
ObservableCollection<ExpandoObject> _list = new ObservableCollection<ExpandoObject>();
dynamic Entity = new ExpandoObject();
Entity.Id = 1;
Entity.Name = "John";
Entity.Age = 22;
_list.Add(Entity);
Entity = new ExpandoObject();
Entity.Id = 2;
Entity.Name = "Date";
Entity.Age = 33;
_list.Add(Entity);
Entity = new ExpandoObject();
Entity.Id = 3;
Entity.Name = "Bob";
Entity.Age = 44;
_list.Add(Entity);

someDatagrid.DataSource = _list;
```

I was expecting to see the columns; Id, Name, Age in the grid but instead I saw only one column with a reference to System.Dynamic.ExpandObject, and it had a child grid showing keyvalue pairs for each property as shown in the attached screenshot.

[image]

How can I dynamically add properties to a class that will end up populating the grid as expected.  Ultimately, I will want to use INotifyPropertyChanged to be able to edit the grid cells and update the business object.

Thank you

Comment: See if this answer is useful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61456901/how-to-create-in-c-sharp-wpf-a-datagrid-dynamic-columns-binded-to-an-observable/61457444#61457444

Comment: Thank you that was an interesting and a good link.  However, its creating a dynamic class and then dynamically adding properties which is cool, but I need to use an existing class and dynamically add fields/properties to it which can be used in databinding such as in a datagrid with dynamic columns.